# ARIMA in state space and Kalman filter for predicted values

Tags: arima, prediction, kalman-filter, dlm

Given the coefficients of an arima Model

```
arimaM <- arima(y, order = c(1,0,2), transform.pars = FALSE, fixed = c(0.5,2,1.5,NA))
```

how can I compute the one step ahead predictions for the observations using the Kalman Filter? I tried

```
result <- dlmFilter(y, mod = arimaM$model, debug = TRUE)
```

returns: Error in t.default(mod$FF) : argument is not a matrix.
The standard approach(es) for calculating predictions does not seem to work for dynamic models. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a model returned by `arima` with `dlmFilter`. Package  `dlm` defines its own objects for ARIMA models: check the documentation for `dlmModARMA` for instance.